# How to hide full screen button of the video tag in HTML5

Tags: html, fullscreen, html5-video

I need to hide the full screen button of the video tag in HTML5.
Is there any way to achieve it ?

[image: Full screen button]

Thanks.

Comment: Currently the `<video>` tag only supports toggling controls with no control over no attributes with the `controls` attribute. The closest you could get to disabling fullscreen is to disable `controls` and making your own control panel.

Comment: Funny that I see all other controls if I add attribute "controls" but the full-screen button is missing.. http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video

Answer (score 49):

I think you can accomplish this by changing the css for the `#document fragments`, these are DOM1 specs and supported by all browsers, but about the styling, I'm not sure.

### Simple `webkit` browser (chrome on windows) specific solution

The following solution is `webkit` specific

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
    display: none;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display{}
video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {}
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deveedutta/TFU4V/5/) for it.

**Warning:**

1. This will not work on browsers who have a rendering engine other than `webkit` e.g. Firefox or Internet Explorer, or obsolete versions of Opera that had Blink/Presto.
2. This may not work with implementations of `webkit` browsers in Operating systems other than windows e.g. Safari on macOS.

**Update:**

After multiple readers complained that the aforementioned solution did not work for certain browsers, I'm updating the answer.

### Taking care of Vendor specific implementations:

- The above solution is `-webkit-` browser specific and was tested in Chrome on Windows.
- The implementation of shadow DOM hasn't been standardized, and therefore, may vary from one browser vendor to another.
- Almost all browsers today have great developer tools, but some features are intentionally locked, but can be opened with a little effort, for instance, in Firefox most such configurations can be accessed in the `about:config` page.
- Developers are advised to unlock the shadow DOM features in their browser.
- Then, they can inspect the `<video>` component

### How to enable shadow DOM selection in Chrome

- Go to Chrome > Developer Tools > Settings (gear icon)
- Under `Elements` look for **Show user agent shadow DOM** option
- Check (select) the box
- You'll be able to inspect the underlying shadow DOM
- Observe their respective styling
- You will notice that they're similar to pseudo class selectors

### Some unsolicited free advise for `Hiding the full screen button of the video tag in HTML5`

- Finding the solution can be as easy as writing CSS with pseudo class selectors
- But like every other CSS, it might require a lot of trial-n-error
- And you might undergo a lot of frustration to make it work
- But always remember, it's worth it.

Additionally, as @paulitto suggests, DOM methods can be implemented after removing `controls` attribute from `<video>` element. Refer [this tutorial](http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/03/custom-html5-video-player) for more.

Comment: I'm using Android's WebView, where the full screen button apparently doesn't work (tested on Android 4.2.2 and 4.4.2). It's not critical if the users of this particular app can't make the videos full screen, so I thought I should find a way to disable the full screen button. This did the trick.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, Nick. Care to share your code?

Comment: @FractalBob - see the [fiddle](jsfiddle.net/deveedutta/TFU4V/5/) & tell me if it doesn't work

Comment: @Nick - Thanks, I saw it, but wasn't sure where the CSS should be inserted in the app.

Comment: I'm using FF, and I see still see the full-screen button from your Fiddle.

Comment: @duyn9uyen - The solution was a suggestion for webkit browsers & Firefox isn't one. One needs replace all `-webkit-` prefixes with `-moz` for similar results. Also, shadow DOM implementation varies from browser-to-browser. Therefore, inspect before applying any CSS.

Comment: this code is working on chrome but i need it work for firefox and safari please anyone help me

Comment: this is not work for mac-chrome,firefox and also safari.

Answer (score 7):

You can disable the fullscreen button using the `controlsList="nofullscreen"` attribute

Supported Browsers: Chrome, Edge, Edge Beta. It doesn't work with Firefox.

[Refer the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvdbrh18/)

**Attribute values:**
`controlsList="nodownload nofullscreen noremoteplayback"`

You must have `controls` attribute in `<video>` tag to get the features of `controlsList`.

[Reference Page](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/media/controlslist.html)

Comment: Mobile devices no supported.

Answer (score 6):

You need just to write this code in your css:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
    display: none;
}
```

And the fulscreen button will hide

Comment: ye this solution work but not in every browswer

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not able to do that without hiding all the controls.
You can use its [dom methods](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) to implement your own controls and design them to look exactly the same as built in controls

Or you can also use external html5 video plugins to implement this

Comment: Nice approach. I saw a [tutorial](http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/03/custom-html5-video-player) on this. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom code for controls

eg. For changing video time use below code

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].currentTime=10;
```

Below link provides all necessary examples to do manual controls on video with javascript

[HTML5 Video Events and API](https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html)