# VideoTag in webview inside dialog in android

Tags: android, webview, html5-video

I am using **webview** inside a **dialog** not **Activity** and using **videoTag** in webview to load a video from url.

if i use Activity than i am able to maximize video but in dialog that button is not maximizing video as per attached screenshot.

and other properties like autoplay is not working for webview.

And i am using VideoEnabledWebview as per [given nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16179544/942224).

i have set also android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

so can i maximize video in webview inside dialog or can i hide maximize button?

[image]

Comment: you can find hiding the fullscreen icon here (but i guess you already found this?!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678302/how-to-hide-full-screen-button-of-the-video-tag-in-html5