# How can I disable the native fullscreen video button from controls in Firefox and IE?

Tags: css, html5-video, html5-fullscreen

To disable the HTML5 video fullscreen button in Chrome/Safari, this CSS works but not in FF/IE:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
        display: none;
    }
```

I found it in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678302/how-to-hide-full-screen-button-of-the-video-tag-in-html5) where there is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deveedutta/TFU4V/5/) that hides the fullscreen button in all browsers.

I duplicated that fiddle in [a CodePen](http://codepen.io/SnapToPixels/pen/xVGLNx) and the results are different. The button is hidden in Chrome/Safari but is showing in FF/IE.
I missed something but I'm not sure what.

```css
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
    display: none;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
   background: red; 
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display{}
video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {}
```

```html
<video width="400" height="260" controls="">
 <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm" type="video/webm" />
 <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because codepen adds an `allowfullscreen` attribute on the iframe containing the pen's document, while jsfiddle doesn't.

So a solution for your problem could be to wrap your video in an iframe without this attribute :

```js
frame.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = '<video src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" controls></video>';
```

```html
<iframe id="frame" width="100%" height="100%" src="about:blank" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Forked codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONyELm

Comment: interesting. I would think the CSS would supersede the iframe attribute. Thanks for the solve. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Retropunk, your CSS is only targeting WebKit browsers. If it does work for others in js fiddle it's because of the iframe.

Comment: the iframe is certainly a fix for now but I was hoping for a CSS fix in FF/IE. At least I understand why it was different between CodePen and JSFiddle...Thanks guys