# Vimeo/self-hosted html5 video: Disable fullscreen mode on mobile

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, vimeo

Is there a way to disable the automatic fullscreen mode of a vimeo video on mobile? It is possible to do it with a youtube video using the "playsinline=1" parameter (like so: https://jsfiddle.net/korgdbf6/),

`<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OYbXaqQ3uuo?playsinline=1;showinfo=0;controls=0;modestbranding=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

but I have failed to do the same with a vimeo video. Is there any possibility to do the same thing with a vimeo video?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: It doesn't seem to be possible... Is there maybe a way to disable automatic fullscreen mode of a self-hosted html5 video?

Comment: Looks like at least since 5 months ago Vimeo has no plans to allow disabling full screen on mobile: https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:268198

Comment: This is what I feared... Thank you anyways! Is there maybe a possibility to disable the automatic fullscreen mode of a self-hosted html5 video?

Comment: Yes as I recall you can remove controls using CSS for the html5 video component: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678302/how-to-hide-full-screen-button-of-the-video-tag-in-html5