# Hide zoom-in control in video tag - Edge and IE

Tags: jquery, css, html, html5-video

I need to remove zoom in control from video tag that appears only in Edge and Internet Explorer. Please have a look at snapshot attached. Searched a bit for the answer, but couldn't find it.

[image]

Code:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls controlsList="nodownload" poster="{{url($sTheme.'/images/xxxx.jpg')}}" preload="none" >
   <source src="{{url($sTheme.'/video/xxxx.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

When right clicked on the zoom in button options for downloading the video is also displayed (Even though download is disabled via controllist)

Comment: I can't check because i'm on mac, but did you try that :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678302/how-to-hide-full-screen-button-of-the-video-tag-in-html5 ?

Comment: Didn't work out for me ..

Answer (score 1):

The `controlsList` attribute is only supported by Chrome 58 and higher.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/controlsList