# How can I disable HTML 5 Video Player full screen button in all kind of browsers, especially in IE, Edge & Firefox, Opera, Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to achieve this in chrome by doing like this..

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
  display: none;
}
```

It is sometimes not working. I need a permanent solution for this very badly.

I am requesting the people:

1. This is not a duplicate question for any other in SO.
2. That solution is not working, test it if you want.

That's why I asked this again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide full screen button of the video tag in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678302/how-to-hide-full-screen-button-of-the-video-tag-in-html5)

Comment: Oh.. No. my dear @Budyn. That solution is not working and it is for chrome only. you can check it out before pushing a down vote. Thanks!!

Comment: I didn't down vote. It just looked identical to me so I gave you an example

Comment: It's okay!! Suggest me any solution if you know about this problem.

Comment: @DaraNaveenKumar as you can see in the answer of user "paulitto" in the linked question it is not possible with css for other browsers than chrome. Btw I don't think you will get a better answer than the one provided in the linked question. Anyway I think you have to use a custom video player if you want to remove the full screen button.

Comment: Firstly, I am thankful to you about all your response through the above comments.
Dear @marcramser, I appreciate your suggestion. But I don't have any option to use third party JS plugins. That's why I'm stick with this. I know lot off JS player plugins are available freely in the market. But my boundaries is like this do not to use other than HTML 5 Video player. Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create you own control (you have to do the styling but I think that should not be a problem).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19np4uxt/5/)

[Tutorial with explanations](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos)

The HTML5:

```
<div id="video-container">
     <!-- Video -->
     <video id="video" width="640" height="365">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <p>
      Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.
      <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/mov_bbb.mp4">Download</a> the video instead.
    </p>
  </video>
  <!-- Video Controls -->
  <div id="video-controls">
    <button type="button" id="play-pause">Play</button>
    <input type="range" id="seek-bar" value="0">
    <button type="button" id="mute">Mute</button>
    <input type="range" id="volume-bar" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
    <button type="button" id="full-screen" disabled>Full-Screen</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this as JavaScript.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  // Video
  var video = document.getElementById("video");

  // Buttons
  var playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause");
  var muteButton = document.getElementById("mute");

  // Sliders
  var seekBar = document.getElementById("seek-bar");
  var volumeBar = document.getElementById("volume-bar");


// Event listener for the play/pause button
playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (video.paused == true) {
    // Play the video
    video.play();

    // Update the button text to 'Pause'
    playButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    // Pause the video
    video.pause();

    // Update the button text to 'Play'
    playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
  }
});

// Event listener for the mute button
muteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (video.muted == false) {
    // Mute the video
    video.muted = true;

    // Update the button text
    muteButton.innerHTML = "Unmute";
  } else {
    // Unmute the video
    video.muted = false;

    // Update the button text
    muteButton.innerHTML = "Mute";
  }
});

// Event listener for the seek bar
seekBar.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // Calculate the new time
  var time = video.duration * (seekBar.value / 100);

  // Update the video time
  video.currentTime = time;
});

// Update the seek bar as the video plays
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
  // Calculate the slider value
  var value = (100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime;

  // Update the slider value
  seekBar.value = value;
});

// Pause the video when the slider handle is being dragged
seekBar.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  video.pause();
});

// Play the video when the slider handle is dropped
seekBar.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  video.play();
});

// Event listener for the volume bar
volumeBar.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // Update the video volume
  video.volume = volumeBar.value;
});

});
```

Comment: Of course, You given me a great solution. But I need all the controlls (seek, pause, play, mute) except full screen. Full screen to be disabled in all browser.

Comment: @DaraNaveenKumar hmm what do you want to say with  "But I need all the controlls (seek, pause, play, mute) except full screen. Full screen to be disabled in all browser."?

Comment: Controls to be enabled: seek, pause, play, mute
Controls to be disabled: FullScreen. That's it i wanna say now..

Comment: No custom controls please.

Comment: Well I don't think that this is possible. Because the <video> tag does not provide an attribute like "showFullScreen=false" this is the way to go if you have to use html 5 video tags.

Comment: And if you need a "full screen button" but disabled you can add this "<button type="button" id="full-screen" disabled>Full-Screen</button>" (I edited my answer)

Comment: It's okay.. Thanks.

Comment: I need to reduce the size of the play/progress bar because when the video is less than 650 pixels wide, the tool bar is wrapping into 2 lines and covering the video.

Comment: Actually its not about size, but to do with CSS that is wrapping the parts... Play on top, next line is the progress slider bar, next line is Mute and next line is volume slider.